# Is there a high temperature glue that I can use on a cook top?

Tags: appliances, glue, cast-iron

We have a 1 year old Frigidaire gas range ([This model](http://www.lowes.com/pd_29714-2251-LGGF3043KF_4294801850+4294965783_4294937087_?productId=3055861&Ns=p_product_prd_lis_ord_nbr%7C0%7C%7Cp_product_qty_sales_dollar%7C1&pl=1&currentURL=/pl_Frigidaire_4294801850%2b4294965783_4294937087_?Ns=p_product_prd_lis_ord_nbr%7C0%7C%7Cp_product_qty_sales_dollar%7C1&facetInfo=Frigidaire) or a near sibling, purchased from Lowes).  The burner grates appear to be painted cast-iron, while the surface below them is a polished and painted metal of some sort.  To protect the lower surface from damage, the grates have several tiny feet.  I'm not sure if the feet are rubber or plastic; they have a texture which is kinda half-way between.

One of these feet has now fallen out.  It has a quarter-inch diameter rod piece, which fits into a hole in the cast-iron.  It doesn't look like anything broke (no residue from tabs on the back end of the foot) but it now freely comes out and won't stay.  So, I'm looking for ways to re-attach the foot.  I'm thinking maybe some form of high-heat industrial glue, which will bond to cast-iron and plastic.  Food safe would probably be a plus; not that it's in contact with food but if the glue gave off fumes when exposed to heat that would be bad.  Are there any glues which meet all these requirements?

**UPDATE**

I finally managed to talk to Frigidaire about this, and thought I'd update with the info they gave me in case anyone wants it in the future.

They do sell an adhesive for this; it's terribly expensive.  Also, these rubber feet things are not covered by warranty, which may explain why not many other people discuss this; it's a part that's expected to fail, and people just ignore it.  Personally, I kinda like my stove top level and un-scratched.

Similar to @Steven, they recommended a high-heat glue.  When I asked about heat requirements, they suggested shopping in automotive supply stores for glues suitable for car engines.  So I'm off to see how those compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A silicon based glue should be able to withstand these temperatures. Makes sure to verify the max temp on the package. [Silicon glue](http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053&productId=202805532&R=202805532)

Answer (score 1):

I was poking around some to see what other were saying about this because I am having the same issue with my stove after replacing some of the rubber feet.  Found something on Amazon that looks like it would work.  Thought I would share.

Red Devil Industrial Grade Heat Resistant Rtv Silicone Sealant
Product Description

Sold as each. 10.1 Oz. Cartridge. Red. When fully cured withstands -85 deg. to 600 deg. F (intermittent). Apply at 10 to 100 deg. F. Seals oven belts, heating elements in appliances, flanged pipe joints, fired heaters, access doors and drying ovens. For porcelain, ceramic, glass, marble, fiberglass, painted surfaces, non-oily surfaces and most metals. Resists cracking, shrinking, peeling and vibration. WIthstands +25% joint movement. Waterproof and weatherproof. Red. UL listed. Meets military spec MIL-A-46106A. Meets FDA regulation No. 21 CFR 1772600 when fully cured and washed. Authorized by USDA for use in federally inspected meat and poultry plants. Manufacturer's number: 0809/0I. Country of origin: United States. Distributed by Red Devil, Inc.

Comment: Dow Corning 736 High Temp RTV Silicone is another that would fit the bill. We use it in the aviation industry.

Answer (score 1):

Sugru is a self-curing, food safe plastic that is relatively high heat tolerant. It's moldable which is a huge plus.